# Derivatives of GHP scalars for typeD spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, kerr-metric

Are there any algebraic expressions for
$\eth \overline \rho$ and $þ (\overline{\tau}')$ in the GHP formalism?

In the specific case of the Kerr metric, by explicit calculation, I managed to prove that

$\eth \overline \rho = þ(\overline{\tau}')= -\frac{1}{2}\left( \tau  \bar{\rho } + \rho  \bar{\tau }'\right)+2 \bar{\rho } \bar{\tau }'$

Does this generalize to any type-D spacetime? Is there a more general expression/ method to obtain it for this?

Thank you for all the help!

**Edit:** Taking derivatives of the Bianchi identities I managed to prove that $\eth \overline \rho = þ(\overline{\tau}')$ in a general vacuum type D spacetime. I am now only interested in the RHS of this

Comment: It is defined in equation 4.12.15 / Section 4.12 of Spinors and Space time Volume-I

Comment: @KP99 isn't that simply the general definition of GHP derivatives in terms of the NP derivatives? Here I am interested in the specific case where $\eta = \overline \rho$ and $\eta = \overline \tau'$

Comment: Oh... Check eqn 4.12.13 where the weights of spin coefficients are mentioned and simply plug it in eqn 4.12.15. You can then invoke the Bianchi identities to write the resulting expression in terms of curvature components (if needed). Everything is mentioned in that section

Comment: @KP99, that is the issue, that procedure will not work here. My issue is not in going from GHP to NP, its the fact that the NP derivatives do not come from Bianchi identities. My question could be reformulated in terms of $D \overline \pi$ and $\delta \overline \rho$. The thing is, if you write these explicitely in terms of tetrad components, the term that usually gives the curvature components looks like $l^\mu l ^ \nu m^ \alpha \nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu n_\alpha$ and by symmetry, it doesn't pick up any contribution from the Rienmann tensor

Comment: It seems that either one could solve for spin coefficient $\rho$ from NP field equations and then compute $\delta \bar{\rho}$ or maybe consider further assumption on choice of null tetrad... For instance, if $l^a$ is defined to be hypersurface orthogonal, then it necessarily implies $\kappa=0$ and $\rho=\bar{\rho}$

Comment: @KP99 I do not think you can pick $l^a$ to be hypersurface orthogonal in a general typed D spacetime, and in particular, in the Kerr case, do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am not sure why there should be such restrictions in choice of spin frame for any algebraically special space time... but I will verify and let you know